# How to run node.js from cwp server?

Tags: node.js

I have a centOS web panel & I don't know how to run my app.js in server. Do you have any idea?
I saw somewhere that is is possible in cPanel but didn't find anything for CWP.

Comment: https://wiki.centos-webpanel.com/how-to-install-and-setup-node-js-on-cwp

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it didn't work.

Comment: For 2021: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=amblG2CPMRM. It appears they've added a module, but not sure why it's in the admin panel and not the user panel.

Answer (score 0):

First install CentOS Development Tools with this command: `yum groupinstall 'Development Tools' -y`

Secondly add the NodeSource repository to the system. For example to for NodeJS v11: `curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_11.x | sudo bash -`

Thirdly install NodeJS with command: `yum install -y nodejs`

The most important step now it to setup a webserver to host NodeJS App. The recommended setup is Nginx with a custom port. Lastly reconfigure and rebuild Webserver Domain Configurations for the domain using this NodeJS app.

Always ensure in the Webserver Domain Configurations to leave ip address as 127.0.0.1.